# Save Kafka messages into HBase through Spark. Session never closes

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to use Spark streaming to receive messages from Kafka, convert them to Put and insert into HBase.
I create a `inputDstream` to receive messages from Kafka and then create a JobConf and finally use `saveAsHadoopDataset(JobConf)` to save records into HBase.

Every time record inserted into HBase, a session from Hbase to zookeeper would be set up but never closes. If number of connections increases more than max client Connections of zookeeper, spark streaming crashes.

my codes are shown below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

object ReceiveKafkaAsDstream {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ReceiveKafkaAsDstream")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    val topics = "test"
    val brokers = "10.0.2.15:6667"

    val topicSet = topics.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)

    val tableName = "KafkaTable"
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    conf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(conf, this.getClass)
    jobConfig.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat", "/user/root/out")
    jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
    jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)

      val records = messages
        .map(_._2)
        .map(SampleKafkaRecord.parseToSampleRecord)
      records.print()  
      records.foreachRDD{ stream => stream.map(SampleKafkaRecord.SampleToHbasePut).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig) }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  case class SampleKafkaRecord(id: String, name: String)
  object SampleKafkaRecord extends Serializable {
    def parseToSampleRecord(line: String): SampleKafkaRecord = {
      val values = line.split(";")
      SampleKafkaRecord(values(0), values(1))
    }

    def SampleToHbasePut(CSVData: SampleKafkaRecord): (ImmutableBytesWritable, Put) = {
      val rowKey = CSVData.id
      val putOnce = new Put(rowKey.getBytes)

      putOnce.addColumn("cf1".getBytes, "column-Name".getBytes, CSVData.name.getBytes)
      return (new ImmutableBytesWritable(rowKey.getBytes), putOnce)
    }
  }
}
```

I set duration of SSC (SparkStreamingContext) as 1s and set maxClientCnxns as 10 in zookeeper conf file zoo.cfg, so there are at most 10 connections allowed from one client to zookeeper.

After 10 seconds (10 sessions set up from HBase to zookeeper), I got the error shown below:

```
16/08/24 14:59:30 WARN RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase-unsecure/hbaseid
16/08/24 14:59:31 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/08/24 14:59:31 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
16/08/24 14:59:31 WARN ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1125)
```

In my understanding, this error exists because number of connections is more than max connection of zookeeper. If I set maxClientCnxn as 20, streaming processing is able to last 20s. I know I can set maxClientCnxn as unlimited, but I really dont think it is a good way solving this problem.

Another thing is if I use TextFileStream to get text files as DStream and save them into hbase using saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf), it runs pretty well. If I just read data from kafka using         `val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)` and simply print info out, there is no issue either. Problem comes when I receive kafka messages and then save them into HBase in the application.

My environment is HDP 2.4 sandbox. versions spark: 1.6, hbase:1.1.2, kafka:2.10.0, zookeeper: 3.4.6.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, finally I get it work.

1. Attribute set:

There is a attributes called "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms". This attribute should be set as 1s.

2. Change to new API:

Change method `saveAsHadoopDataset(JobConf)` to `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(JobConf)`. I still dont know why the old API is not working.

Change `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat` to `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat`

Comment: extremly helpful. Thank you.